# Is there any way to change language input icons on macOS?

Tags: macos, icon, language, input-source

Some languages like Spanish and Russian use the country flags for language input, while others like Chinese and Japanese are not. So I would like to change language input icons such that all languages have the country flags for aesthetics. I also want to set different icons to different input system on Japanese.

Is this possible on macOS?

(I use Big Sur Beta 2 but a solution on Catalina is totally fine.)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this as far as I know is to create custom keyboards with a app like [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/), where you can create any icon you want for a layout.  But Ukelele cannot make custom keyboards for complex "input methods" like Chinese and Japanese.